# Delete all model queries in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app

```
 AllAdjustments::deleteAll(['plan_year_id' => $plan_year_id, 'column_type' => array_keys($allAdjustment), 'is_auto' => $is_auto,
                ['NOT',['column_id'=>1]], 
            ]);
```

getting error error: "strtoupper() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given1188C:\xampp\htdocs\sir-git\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\db\QueryBuilder.php"

Answer (score 0):

you may try this solution:

```
AllAdjustments::deleteAll(
        [
            "AND",
            [
                'plan_year_id' => $plan_year_id,
                'column_type' => array_keys($allAdjustment),
                'is_auto' => $is_auto,
            ],
            ['NOT',['column_id'=>1]]
        ]
    )
```